# ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: xcode

while trying to run in Xcode 7.3.1, I am getting the following error :

Ld /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble\ iOS.app/birdybobble\ iOS normal i386
    cd /Volumes/WORK/birdybobble/proj.ios_mac
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -Lsdkbox.framework -LPluginChartboost.framework -LChartboost.framework -LPluginAdMob.framework -LGoogleMobileAds.framework -LPluginIAP.framework -F/Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Volumes/WORK/birdybobble/proj.ios_mac -filelist /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Intermediates/birdybobble.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/birdybobble\ iOS.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -lbz2.1.0 -lz.1 -framework OpenGLES -framework UIKit -framework CoreMotion -framework Security /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d\ iOS.a -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework sdkbox -framework PluginChartboost -framework Chartboost -framework StoreKit -framework AdSupport -framework SystemConfiguration -framework PluginAdMob -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework MessageUI -framework GameController -framework MediaPlayer -framework PluginIAP -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Intermediates/birdybobble.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/birdybobble\ iOS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble\ iOS.app/birdybobble\ iOS

duplicate symbol _strerror$UNIX2003 in:
    /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Intermediates/birdybobble.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/asd.o
    /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d iOS.a(CCImage.o)
duplicate symbol _fopen$UNIX2003 in:
    /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Intermediates/birdybobble.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/asd.o
    /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d iOS.a(CCImage.o)
duplicate symbol _fwrite$UNIX2003 in:
    /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Intermediates/birdybobble.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/birdybobble iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/asd.o
    /Users/ecdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birdybobble-hfiarbprydmxgtbmjresfgzerqom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d iOS.a(CCImage.o)
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If someone can help, it will be a great help !!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From **Xcode 7.3** onwards you can you can's use any custom variable twice. If you want to use then just Go to **Build Setting** and search for **No Common Blocks** and set it **NO**. And build again you will not get this error again.